# Let's improve the question guidance for new users

Tags: discussion, new-users

As described in [this Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377058/what-site-specific-changes-can-be-made-to-the-ask-question-page-to-help-askers-o) post, individual Stack Exchange communities are able to customize particular elements of the ["Ask a public question"](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). The *exact* things that can be modified are quite particular, so please consider taking a look at the linked Meta.SE post.

We encourage you to open the ["Ask a public question"](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page in an incognito/private window to refresh yourself on what it looks like currently.

Frequent, off-topic questions requesting personal medical advice are a [constant frustration](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/discussion-what-is-needed-for-this-site-to-work?cb=1) to many of our regular users. Although we are unlikely to be able to reach *every* new user, we can at least try to discourage these types of questions and those that do not show any prior research.

Therefore, the moderator team suggests that we provide additional guidance in the **Asking a good question** and **Step 1. Draft your question** dialogs.

Here is the current state, along with an initial suggestion for improvement.

[image]

[image]

##### What we need from you.

1. Below are community wiki answers containing the text to be added. We invite you to **make edits** to improve what is presented.
2. Please upvote the answers if you agree that the proposed changes effectively communicate the community consensus.

Answer (score 5):

##### Asking a good question

- **Questions requesting medical advice are not allowed here.** This includes questions regarding specific medical cases or those related to your own or anyone's health. Such concerns should be taken to your personal healthcare provider.
- [We expect](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research) you to have done at least some **research prior to asking.** Please include links, quotes, or references to what you have found.

Comment: Because there have been so many complaints recently that questions were somehow not „asking for medical advice“, maybe we can reword that part? How about: „Questions regarding specific medical cases and questions that are personally related to your own or anyone‘s health cannot be asked here“?

Comment: Although this is not as succinct. Alternatively: „Questions that are related to your (or a relative‘s) health and questions asking for medical advice cannot be asked here“, which is a bit shorter and more succinct?

Comment: How about a new sentence after the bolded one, "This includes questions regarding specific medical cases or those related to your own or anyone's health."?

Comment: I like that suggestion!

Comment: "Cannot" is not the right word.

Comment: @user1271772 That's fair, how about "may not"?

Comment: Or "are not allowed". Or better "will be closed" (since that is literally what will happen, it seems).

Comment: @user1271772 "Will be closed" is obvious to us, because we know the Stack Exchange network, but if you land here from Google and ask your first question, it's probably just jargon.

Comment: I think it's fairly clear to non-SE users with enough English vocabulary to ask a question here in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

##### Step 1: Draft your question

**Questions about your own health or anyone else's health are off-topic. Such concerns should be taken to a personal healthcare provider.**

[We expect](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research) you to have done some research prior to asking. Please be sure to remember to include links, quotes, or references to what you have found so far.

Comment: This is more about the comments on the other question, but I wonder if it makes more sense to add further detail here and also to use complementary language. If I understand correctly, this part is text that will appear continually for question-askers, whereas the other is a one-time popup. Perhaps, "**Questions about your own health or anyone else's health are off-topic. Such concerns should be taken to your personal healthcare provider.**"

Comment: @BryanKrause I think this is the best wording yet.